# Class not found error for com.sun.tool.javac in OSGI

Tags: dynamic, compilation, osgi

I am *porting an old Java code base to OSGI*. In the old code base there is dynamic code generation used. Example a string is compiled to generate Java classes using
`com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile`.

I was reusing the same code and added `com.sun.tools.javac` in `etc/custom.properties` *->* `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra:= com.sun.tools.javac.Main` of Karaf.

During runtime I get the exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main`

Could anyone please help me out with some suggestions to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Karaf but why do you use := instead of just = in the property setting? Also, the property value is a list of package names, not type names. So the interesting package is "com.sun.tools.javac".

Comment: Sorry it was a typo in fact i have used org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra = com.sun.tools.javac only. As I understand the org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra tells the karaf container to load additional packages that are not loaded by default. If I remove com.sun.tool.javac many of my bundles does not get started. If I add that they gets started but during runtime getting the error.

Comment: Is the com.sun.tools.javac package visible to the framework impl's class loader?

Comment: Hi, I was able to solve the problem. I made a bundle called "SunTools" with tools.jar and exposed the required packages in Export-Package and deployed it.